# How do I apply effects made in the compositor to the Blender VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, video, effects

I recently did some green screen compositing and color grading for some footage in Blender's compositor. I would like to learn how to apply these effects to a video strip in the video sequence editor, so that I can render all of my footage with audio in a fast, efficient way.

Is this possible to do in Blender? If not, how can I solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.